# Twitter chunked video upload authorization

Tags: java, video, twitter, oauth, upload

I want to upload video on Twitter from my java web application via a POST request. For that, I have implemented the INIT, APPEND and FINALIZE command. I'm able to generate the signature from the different OAUTH keys that I have.

My question: should I send the OAUTH parameters (oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_token, oauth_version) with every command to the https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json endpoint?

This [link](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media/uploading-media#chunkedupload) gives more informations about the twitter media chunked upload.

Thanks!

Comment: @Lig Did you do this successfully, you would need to pass authorization at every request.